# My knob drawn with Swing is ugly. Why?

Tags: java, swing

I'm drawing a knob as a component and I'm using swing. The result seems ok but when I click on the knob and move my mouse (up or down) to change the knob position, the knob repainted is ugly, as if there were 2 layers superposed. More over, I have this result only for the "small sizes" of my knob. If I enlarge my frame, this ugly effect disappear. Does someone could explain me what happens and how to improve my knob ?

Thanks a lot for those who will help me.

Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Knob extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
int length, originX, originY, centerX, centerY, width, height, diameter, squareLength;
int minorTick, majorTick, xTick, yTick, xCursor, yCursor;
int xMouse, yMouse, xMouseOrigin, yMouseOrigin;
float yDeltaMouse;
double angleOrigin, angleRange, angle;
double cursorValue;
double initialCursorValue;
Color backgroundColor, knobColor;
boolean mousePressed;
Thread t;
private double knobValue;
private String title = new String("");
private int titleWidth;

Knob (double initialValue, Color c, int majorTick, int minorTick) {
    //System.out.println("Knob");
    cursorValue=initialCursorValue=initialValue;
    knobColor =c;       
    this.majorTick=majorTick;
    this.minorTick=minorTick;       

    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

Knob (double initialValue, Color c, int majorTick, int minorTick, String title) {
    //System.out.println("Knob");
    cursorValue=initialCursorValue=initialValue;
    knobColor =c;       
    this.majorTick=majorTick;
    this.minorTick=minorTick;
    this.title=title;

    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    width=this.getWidth()/10*10;
    height=this.getHeight()/10*10;

    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "on");
    System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
    g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    if (width>height) {
        length=height;
    } else {
        length=width;
    }
    centerX=width/2;
    centerY=height/2;

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    squareLength = (int )(length*0.9);
    originX=(width-squareLength)/2;
    originY=(height-squareLength)/2;

    /*
    //-45 = (-(Math.PI)/4)
    angleOrigin= -45;
    // 270 = (3*(Math.PI)/2)
    angleRange=270;
    //g.drawRect(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength);
    //g.fillArc(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength, (int)angleOrigin, (int)angleRange);
    for (int i=0; i<minorTick ; i++) {
        angle=((i*angleRange/(minorTick-1))+angleOrigin)-7;
        //System.out.println(angle*360/(2*Math.PI));
        xTick= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*squareLength/2);
        yTick= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*squareLength/2);
        //g.drawLine(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick);
        //g.fillArc(originX, originY, squareLength, squareLength, (int)angle, (int)14);
    }
    */

    angleOrigin=-(Math.PI)/4;
    angleRange=3*(Math.PI)/2;       
    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(length/50+1));        
    for (int i=0; i<minorTick ; i++) {
        angle=i*angleRange/(minorTick-1)+angleOrigin;
        //System.out.println(angle*360/(2*Math.PI));
        xTick= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*squareLength/2);
        yTick= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*squareLength/2);
        //g.drawLine(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick);
        g2D.draw (new Line2D.Float(centerX, centerY, xTick, yTick));
    }

    backgroundColor = this.getBackground();
    g.setColor(backgroundColor);
    diameter=(int)(length*0.8);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.fillOval(originX, originY, diameter, diameter);


    /*
    RadialGradientPaint gp;
    Point2D center= new Point2D.Float(width/2, height/2);
    diameter=(int)(length*0.75);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    float radius=diameter/2;        
    float[] dist = {0.7f, 1f};
    Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GRAY};
    gp=new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
    g2D.setPaint(gp);       
    g2D.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);
    */
    diameter=(int)(length*0.75);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);

    diameter=(int)(length*0.7);
    originX=(width-diameter)/2;
    originY=(height-diameter)/2;
    g.setColor(knobColor);
    g.fillOval(originX,originY,diameter,diameter);


    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(length/50+3));
    angle=(2*Math.PI)*(0.75-cursorValue*0.75)+angleOrigin;
    xCursor= (int) (centerX+Math.cos(angle)*length*0.35);
    yCursor= (int) (centerY-Math.sin(angle)*length*0.35);
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g2D.draw (new Line2D.Float(centerX, centerY, xCursor, yCursor));

    g2D.rotate(Math.toRadians(270.0));
    g.setFont(new Font(g.getFont().getFontName(),Font.PLAIN,this.getHeight()/3));
    titleWidth=g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(title);
    g2D.drawString(title,-this.getHeight()+titleWidth/3,this.getHeight()/4);        
    //System.out.println(titleWidth);
    //System.out.println(this.getHeight()*(-70)/100+" - "+this.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Bouton : "+arg0.getButton());

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Bouton : "+arg0.getButton());
    PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point mouseLocation = pointer.getLocation();
    xMouseOrigin = (int) mouseLocation.getX();
    yMouseOrigin = (int) mouseLocation.getY();
    if (arg0.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        mousePressed=true;
        t= new Thread(new TrackPosition());
        t.start();
    } else if (arg0.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        cursorValue=initialCursorValue;
        repaint();
        knobValue=cursorValue;
    }       
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mousePressed=false;
    //System.out.println("Mouse released");     
    repaint();      
}

class TrackPosition implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (mousePressed==true) {
            PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point mouseLocation = pointer.getLocation();
            yMouse = (int) mouseLocation.getY();
            yDeltaMouse=(float)(yMouse-yMouseOrigin)/100;
            cursorValue=cursorValue+yDeltaMouse;
            yMouseOrigin=yMouse;
            if (cursorValue >=1) {
                cursorValue=1;
            } else if (cursorValue <= 0) {
                cursorValue=0;
            }
            //This repaint is a problem if I "uncomment" it
            repaint();
            knobValue=cursorValue;
        }           
    }       
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,70);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new Knob(0.5, new Color(0,255,0,255), 3, 9, "Gain"));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Post a screenshot so we know what you are talking about...

Comment: More of a design solution but small knobs everywhere can be off putting.
Can you put your knob in some kind of container and reveal it when needed by the user. Then you never need see it in its "small sizes"?

Comment: Good idea too. I keep it in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss to call the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method from `JComponent`.

Changing your code as below will solve the problem.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```